# How to resolve Underflow (/Overflow) issues in Fixed-Point tool of MATLAB Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, fixed-point

Thanks in advance

I am working on a Simulink model which involves Floating-point data types. So using the Fixed-Point tool available in Simulink, I am trying to convert my floating-point system to a fixed-point one. I am following the tutorial available here to achieve the conversion.

[Link to the tutorial on converting the floating-point system to the fixed point](https://in.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/tutorial-steps.html)

[image]

In the Data type proposing step, I got underflow values for some of the variables. My question is how to convert those underflow values as well in-range. Or can I ignore them and proceed with further steps? In general how to tackle this type of underflow/overflow issue?

Answer (score 2):

Using fixed-point arithmetic can be faster and use less resources than floating-point arithmetic, but a significant disadvantage is that underflow and overflow are not handled gracefully. If you try to detect and recover from these conditions you will lose much of the advantage provided by fixed-point.

In practice, you should select a fixed-point format for your variables that provides enough bits for the integer part (the bits to the left of the radix point) so that overflow cannot occur. This requires careful analysis of your algorithms and the potential ranges of all variables. Your format should also provide enough fraction bits (to the right of the radix point) so that underflows do not cause significant problems with your algorithm.

Comment: Some amount of dynamic re-scaling (in essence, changing to a different fixed-point format) in some intermediate computations is usually tolerable and keeps resource usage in the common path low. If the use case requires a high dynamic range, fixed-point arithmetic may be the wrong tool for the job.